# journalctl missing "Logs begin at" on Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: 22.04, systemd-journald

When I run `journalctl -u <unit> -n 10` on Ubuntu 20.04 the first output line is:

```
Logs begin at ..., end at ...
```

When I run the same command on 22.04, this information is missing. Is there a way/argument to get it back?